# SubsamplingScaleImageView and OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview, out-of-memory, android-glide

I use SubsamplingScaleImageView to show image. But on some devices java.lang.OutOfMemoryError appears. Usually I used Glide to fix that, but it does not work with SubsamplingScaleImageView.

Is it possible to use Glide in my case?

Answer (score 0):

according to these, the issue has been resolve by this:

https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view/issues/369

and this commit

https://github.com/tibbi/subsampling-scale-image-view/commit/6d880a617e8818d4d0372482978163c8005c26bf#

Comment: I use the latest version and have the same crash. I wrote to the developer.